# Move away from textbox using tab button

Tags: windows-7, input

I was wondering about this for quite some time now.

This applies to pretty much every software that has multiline inputs at some point, but I will give an example with a webpage since it's "more universal".

Let's say you are filling up a form in a web page. That has the following fields:

- A single line text `input` named "username"
- Another one named "email"
- A big "comments" section represented by a `textarea`.
- A "Visible" `checkbox` input.
- And finally a "Submit" `button` to complete the submission (obviously).

Let's say that you use the mouse to focus on the first input.

You type in your username and click `Tab` to move to the next input.

You enter your email and again move to the next input using `Tab`.
Your cursor is now sitting on the glorious "comments" `textarea` and start typing a comment. As long as you are finished, you hit tab and realize that instead of moving to the checkbox, you insert a tab character in the textarea while the cursor remains hooked.

Is there any combination of keys to move out of the textarea, when the `Tab` button inserts a tab character?

P.S. As I see while typing this question, the textarea SO provides allows moving to the next field with the `Tab` button, so it has something to do with Javascript. What can be done to other software though?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this on IE, Firefox and Chrome. Ervery browser i tested will focus the next element if `tab` is pressed in a `textarea`. There is a question `Use tab indent in textarea` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637341/use-tab-to-indent-in-textarea) which adresses the opposite problem.

Maybe your question is related to `Windows Forms` (VBA in Access, Excel, etc.) but that's only a guess.

Could you clarify your question that we know which "other software" you mean.